# arangodb 2.2.4 - foxx manager install command returning cannot write file

Tags: arangodb

I have installed arangodb 2.2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 and created new database "SampleDB" using arangodb web interface.

then executed following commands

`foxx-manager --server.database SampleDB update`

`foxx-manager --server.database SampleDB install hello-foxx /hello`

but the command is returning error "cannot write file".

I have checked the logs but could not find anything. Same error is coming if i am trying to install from arangosh.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this problem, even with arangodb 2.2.5.

Here is what happens in the ArangoDB database:

1. foxx-manager simply calls arangosh
2. arangosh creates a temporary directory /tmp/arangodb with the current user
    as owner
3. foxx-manager puts some stuff in there,
4. the dir stays
5. either you did not reboot or Ubuntu 14.04 does not clean /tmp on reboot,
6. if then another user tries to use foxx-manager, the directory is still there
    and the new arangosh under the new user cannot write, which leads to the
    error

Solution:
  for the moment, remove /tmp/arangodb if it is in the way

I will now change arangosh such that it uses a unique name in /tmp for the temporary directory and possibly cleans that one up in the end. This should
solve the problem. I will post here which version will have the fix.

Comment: Quick update: If you add "--temp-path /tmp/MYOWNPATH" to the foxx-manager command, it should work immediately, but this is of course only a quick fix.

Comment: This is now fixed in the 2.2 branch and the change will appear with 2.2.6.